# Does Minikube Ignore the Worker Node's Port Number Used?

Tags: kubectl, minikube, portforwarding

I am new to Minikube, and I tried to run a simple Docker container in Minikube. After creating the deployment, I tried 2 ways, first I exposed the deployment (the name of the deployment is "tetris", and the application is using Port 80) using type=NodePort:

`kubectl expose deployment tetris --type=NodePort --port=80`

Then I found out which port in the worker node is used:

```
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes       ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          3d23h
tetris           NodePort    10.106.96.20    <none>        80:31180/TCP     92s
```

Next, I tried to create a tunnel with:

`kubectl port-forward tetris-6ccf4788cb-gsst8 31280:31180`

But I got an error once I tried to load the application in the web browser using localhost:31280

```
E1206 04:00:19.097656   22468 portforward.go:409] an error occurred forwarding 31280 -> 31180: error forwarding port 31180 to pod 48105c5b76d23937bd096e9f22d3e0172ca04e169d15dfae005efac050c26538, uid : exit status 1: 2023/12/05 20:00:19 socat[176004] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:31180, 16): Connection refused
error: lost connection to pod
```

Instead, if I forwarded port 80, the application worked well:

`kubectl port-forward tetris-6ccf4788cb-gsst8 31280:80`

But this seems unreasonable, since the Port 31180 in the worker node was not used at all.

I tried to delete the service and exposed the deployment again with type=LoadBalancer, but the result was still the same.

What should I do to make use of the Port 31180 of the worker node while making the application work in Minikube?